# setCookie before headers are sent?

Tags: headers, cookies

I was using this code in my plugin to set a cookie if a condition was met, however after updating to Wordpress 4.0 I got the message:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

How can I set the cookie before headers are sent? This is my code:

```
    // Add Cookie if Admin
    if (current_user_can('manage_options') || !empty($_COOKIE["loggedAdmin"])) 
        {
        setcookie("loggedAdmin", "true", time()+3600*24*365);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code hooked to? Which action?

Comment: hi I hooked it to init `add_action('init', array('Pranalog_Analytics', 'detect_admins'));` still I keep getting that error. Also it says the input started on functions.php but I see nothing wrong there

Comment: Look at the file it is pointing to. Perhaps it has a blank line at the top or bottom of the file that it should not have.

Comment: I checked but there was none. I copied the content to a new file and the problem was gone, I think it might have been a problem with utf bom